# Drupal automatic TFA

Tags: 7, users

I want to setup the Two-factor Authentication ([TFA](https://www.drupal.org/project/tfa)) configuration automatically for each user that signs up in my site. Is that possible?

Because from what I have tried till now, all the users for whom I want TFA to be active needs to be configured individually. But shouldn't the ideal situation be such that the TFA will get active per user as soon as the user gets in the system?

What am I missing here? Isn't this a very obvious requirement?

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no mechanism to require existing users to use TFA; if you use "authenticated user" with "Roles required to have set up TFA", then new users cannot set up TFA and existing users without TFA will not be able to log in.

[image: TFA rejecting newly created user]

TFA doesn't provide any mechanism for this, so I wrote a module that provides Rules integration and created a basic rule that would do it.

https://www.drupal.org/project/tfa_rules

Instructions on setting up basic TFA on a site:

Download and install Two-Factor Authentication, TFA Basic Plugins, Rules and TFA Rules

```
drush dl tfa tfa_basic rules tfa_rules
```

Enable.

```
drush -y en tfa tfa_basic rules rules_admin tfa_rules
```

Configure TFA: /admin/config/people/tfa

- [X] Enable TFA
- Default validation plugin: TOTP
- [Save configuration]

Configure permissions: /admin/people/permissions

- Set up TFA for account

  - [X] authenticated user
- [Save permissions]

Visit /admin/config/workflow/rules to configure the rule.

Testing:

- Log out
- Create a user
- Login
- User will be redirected to the security page to set up TFA.

[image: TFA Rules message]